# Make all elements with space underneath in list drop one row

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a Samegame/Candy Crush clone in Python 3.3.3, according to the rules of the game, when multiple cells are cleared, those who were above have to "fall down" to fill the empty spaces.

Basically I have something that looks like this:

```
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15
-----------------------------------------------
1 |@  @  #  &  @  @  @  @  @  &  &  @  #  @  & |1
2 |@  #  &  @  &  @  @  &  @  #  &  &  &  @  & |2
3 |@  &  #  @  &  &  @  @  &  #  &  &  #  #  & |3
4 |      @  #  &  &  #  &  #  @  #  @  @  @  & |4
5 |      &  @        &  #  #  #  @  &  @  @  & |5
6 |&              &  &  #  &  @  #  @  #  &  @ |6
7 |@  @     &        &  &  &  @  @  &  #  &  & |7
8 |@        &  @     &  &  &  &  @  @  #  @  @ |8
9 |@     @  @        &  @  @  #  #  @  #  #  # |9
10|#  @  @  &  &  &  #  &  #  #  &  @  &  #  # |10
-----------------------------------------------
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15
```

And I want to make it look like this:

```
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15
-----------------------------------------------
1 |                  @  @  @  &  &  @  #  @  & |1
2 |         &        @  &  @  #  &  &  &  @  & |2
3 |@        @        @  @  &  #  &  &  #  #  & |3
4 |@     #  @        #  &  #  @  #  @  @  @  & |4
5 |@     &  #  @  @  &  #  #  #  @  &  @  @  & |5
6 |&  @  #  @  &  @  &  #  &  @  #  @  #  &  @ |6
7 |@  #  @  &  &  &  &  &  &  @  @  &  #  &  & |7
8 |@  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  @  @  #  @  @ |8
9 |@  @  @  @  @  &  &  @  @  #  #  @  #  #  # |9
10|#  @  @  &  &  &  #  &  #  #  &  @  &  #  # |10
-----------------------------------------------
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15
```

Here is the code that I have to achieve this:

```
game = [
    ['@','@','#','&','@','@','@','@','@','&','&','@','#','@','&'],
    ['@','#','&','@','&','@','@','&','@','#','&','&','&','@','&'],
    ['@','&','#','@','&','&','@','@','&','#','&','&','#','#','&'],
    ['#','#','@','#','&','&','#','&','#','@','#','@','@','@','&'],
    ['#','#','&','@','#','#','&','#','#','#','@','&','@','@','&'],
    ['&','#','#','#','#','&','&','#','&','@','#','@','#','&','@'],
    ['@','@','#','&','#','#','&','&','&','@','@','&','#','&','&'],
    ['@','#','#','&','@','#','&','&','&','&','@','@','#','@','@'],
    ['@','#','@','@','#','#','&','@','@','#','#','@','#','#','#'],
    ['#','@','@','&','&','&','#','&','#','#','&','@','&','#','#']
] # Of course during the game, this board won't stay the same

def collapse_board():
    for i in range(1, 15):
        empty = 9
        full = empty
        while empty >= 0 and full >= 0:
            while empty >= 0 and game[empty][i] != ' ':
                empty -= 1
            if empty >= 0:
                full = empty - 1
                while full >= 0 and game[full][i] == ' ':
                    full -= 1
                if full >= 0:
                    game[empty][i] = game[full][i]
                    game[full][i]
```

Results in this:

```
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15
-----------------------------------------------
1 |@  @  #  &  @  @  @  @  @  &  &  @  #  @  & |1
2 |@  #  &  @  &  @  @  &  @  #  &  &  &  @  & |2
3 |@  &  #  @  &  &  @  @  &  #  &  &  #  #  & |3
4 |   &  @  #  &  &  #  &  #  @  #  @  @  @  & |4
5 |   &  &  @  &  &  &  #  #  #  @  &  @  @  & |5
6 |&  &  &  #  &  &  &  #  &  @  #  @  #  &  @ |6
7 |@  @  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  @  @  &  #  &  & |7
8 |@  @  &  &  @  &  &  &  &  &  @  @  #  @  @ |8
9 |@  @  @  @  @  &  &  @  @  #  #  @  #  #  # |9
10|#  @  @  &  &  &  #  &  #  #  &  @  &  #  # |10
-----------------------------------------------
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is exacerbated by the datastructure you are using. Although it is suitable for printing, it is not especially good for performing the operation you want to perform.

You need to use, or create a datastructure which supports row and column operations. You might like to use a `numpy` `array` to store this data, and then manipulate it with slicing operations.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, a list of lists doesn't make changing columns easy.  One way -- not particularly efficient, but convenient -- would be to transpose `game` so that columns became rows, change the "rows", and then transpose back.  (If you only ever perform this kind of operation on columns, then maybe it would make sense to store the matrix transposed.)  Even if you didn't want to wrap everything up in a class, you could write utility functions like `get_column` and `set_column` so you wouldn't have to keep repeating the logic.

Without doing any of that, though, the collapse logic can still be made a lot simpler:

```
def collapse(vec, empty_marker=' '):
    nonempty = [x for x in vec if x != empty_marker]
    padded = [empty_marker]*(len(vec)-len(nonempty)) + nonempty
    return padded

for col_ind in range(len(game[0])):
    col = [row[col_ind] for row in game]
    collapsed = collapse(col)
    for row, to_set in zip(game, collapsed):
        row[col_ind] = to_set
```

`collapse` collects all the non-empty cells and then adds the right number of empty markers to the start to fill it up.

```
>>> collapse(list("ABC D EF"))
[' ', ' ', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
```

You could also sort, although that would be (algorithmically) slower for large grids, and might be too cute.  It takes advantage of the fact that you can pass a `key` argument to `sorted`, and that `False == 0` and `True == 1`.  So if you make the condition something which is `False` for what you want first, it'll give you what you're looking for:

```
>>> sorted("ABC D EF", key=lambda x: x != " ")
[' ', ' ', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
```

Comment: I see, I should've thought my data structure more through. Thank you for your help, I've learned a lot